# How to set language for a Vonage's sms in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, sms, locale, vonage

I am working on a `Laravel` app the sends `sms` in different languages including `Bulgarian` but when I send text in bulgarian I get `???????`. There is no information about sms' language for Vonage on the internet. Is that even possible?

I browsed and searched the Vonage PHP SDK code but found no reference to language or locale.

I have this code inside a job to send the SMS:

```
$message = new \Vonage\SMS\Message\SMS($this->phone, "App", $this->message);

Vonage::sms()->send($message);
```

Any ideas?